# Fast Way to retrieve data from mysql 5.0 and pushing in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MYSQL 5.0 & PHP . In my Database I am having 1 Million USERS entries. Now i am using 
following query.

**`SELECT ID FROM USERS;`**

fetching these values in PHP array for the further use like as follow .

```
$Userid = array();
for($i=0;$<sizeof($IDArray);$i++)
{
$Userid[$i] = $IDArray[$i];
}
```

This method is so expensive for me , taking huge time & bursting my further operations. 
Mysql INDEX method i am not able to use here. Suggest any method which i can use here.

I am trying to collect all ID(Primary Key) from user table . Using all users IDs , i am going to calculate how many comment , views on a particular article post of the users.

For Eg. ID = 1

On Id 1 , one user registered for example Smith Joseph. Smith having 10 Article Post.
I want to write a program to find the on which Article post having maximum views and comment count.

I hope the idea is clear now !

Comment: How about not pulling the whole table at once and instead add some kind of pagination? Pulling 1 million records in one shot seems like a bad idea.

Comment: There is no real world usage of fetching all rows in a table, and only use the id. elaborate on what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Can't you do some `count()` on your SQL query instead? It seems you're practically caching everything in PHP and count it yourself.

Comment: Count() I am using ... For executing POST Count of every user , I required all POST ID .

Comment: you can use SQL to do all the task, simple joins would help.